# What is the equivalent to Platform.flush() in Dart?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, polymer-designer-tool

I was trying to migrate one library from polymer.js to polymer.dart and I found this line:

```
Platform.flush()
```

And I was wondering what is the equivalent in dart.

this line appears on line 32 in next library:

https://github.com/Polymer/designer/blob/master/elements/design-state/design-state.html

Comment: It might help to show the code that uses Platform.flush(). What library are you trying to migrate?

Comment: I'm trying to migrate design-state.html

Answer (score 2):

There isn't and you shouldn't need it in Polymer.dart but you might for interop with Polymer.js.
A workaround is to use JS-interop:

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js show context;

...

js.context['Platform'].callMethod('flush')
```

When you call `async(...)` or `asyncTimer(...)` of your Polymer element `Platform.flush()` is called from Polymer.dart code.